# Macro only running through first result

Tags: excel, vba

The below code only seems to work on the first result. I have to re-run it for the other results to be removed. Could anyone take a look and tell me why please? Thanks

I've tried copy and pasting the code several times to compensate but it gives me an error about duplicate code

```vb
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In [AE1:AE2000]
    If cell.Value = "REMOVE" Then Range(cell.Offset(0, -5).Address & ":" & cell.Offset(0, 0).Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next cell
```

Comment: When deleting you want to use a normal for loop and loop backwards.

Comment: You delete cells from the same range area you delete cells from? You loop from top-to-bottom? Try to make a cell loop from bottom-to-up so that deletion does not change the view of the remaining range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you must do when deleting rows is loop backwards; otherwise you may skip rows, which is what is happening to you by the sounds of it. You have to use a counter when looping backwards, such as

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, cell As Range

Set cell = Range("AE1:AE2000")

For r = cell.Count To 1 Step -1
    If UCase(cell(r).Value) = "REMOVE" Then
        Range(cell(r).Offset(0, -5), cell(r)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much.